# Using Slick Carousel to have three different picture cycles

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to us Slick Carousel to make a slide show for three different `div` containers (example below). Each container would have three pictures that it should cycle through. When I add 1 image to each of the containers under the class "pic" the layout is correct, but when I add the other 2 images to each of the containers and refresh the page all the images are extremely stretched out and the layout and positions are messed up. Excuse the poor representation of the example I don't know how to show the JavaScript and have it work in the preview section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Why OneDrive?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/styles.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c83075ea7c.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
    <script src="../JS/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
              crossorigin="anonymous">     
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/3picslideshow.js"></script>        
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#Home" class="menu-item-select">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#Home" class="menu-item-select">Usage</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-child">
                    <a href="#Home" class="menu-item-select">About<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Pricing</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Extra Information</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Related</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#Home" class="menu-item-select">Acknowledgments</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="column-container">

        <div class="row-container">

            <div class="home-carousel-grid">

                <div class="home-carousel">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src="../Pictures/OneDrive-Clouds-Text-Logo.png" alt="">

                    </div>
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src="../Pictures/OneDrive-Clouds-Logo.png" alt="">

                    </div>
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src="../Pictures/OneDrive-Sync-Logo.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="pic-intro">
            <h1>OneDrive A Cloud Based Storage System!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="home-content">
            <div class="content">
                <p>With OneDrive You Can:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Sync To Multiple Devices.</li>
                    <li>See All Of Your Information From Any Device.</li>
                    <li>Oragnize Your Folders and Subfolders</li>
                    <li>Buy The Amount of Space That You Need! </li>
                    <li>Share Individual Folders or Files with Colleagues.</li>
                </ul>
                <div class ="button">
                    <a href="https://onedrive.com">See What OneDrive Can Do For You</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content content-pics">
                <img src="../Pictures/OneDrive-Sync-Logo.png">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html> 

html{
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind);
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: white;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;


}

ul.main-menu{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 100%;

}

li.menu-item{



}

a.menu-item-select{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #808080;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 14px;
}

a.menu-item-select:hover{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #DFE1E5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 14px;


}

a.menu-item-has-child{
    position: relative;
}

.sub-nav {
    display: none;
    background:    #D3D3D3;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-weight: normal;
      list-style: none;

}

.sub-nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #808080;



 }

 .sub-nav a:hover{
    color:     #094AB2;
}

.sub-nav li{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 50%; 
    text-align: center;
}



li:hover > .sub-nav{
    display: flex;
      flex-direction: column; 
      align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
 }

 .column-container{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
 }

 .pic-intro{
     text-align: center;
     color: #091E42;
     border-bottom: solid 2px #094AB2;


 }

  .row-container{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
 }

 .home-content{
     display: flex;
     padding-left: 5%;

 }

 .content{
    width: 33.3%;
    color: #091E42;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

 .content-pics img{
    height:150px;

 }

 .button a{
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #091E42;
    background-color: #b3ffe6;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    transition: 4s;


 }

 .button a:hover{
     transition: 2s;
    background-color: #00e699;


 }

 .button{
    text-align: center;

 }

 .home-carousel{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;


 }

$( document ).ready(function() {

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.pic').slick({

      });
    });

});
```

Comment: Its going to be pretty difficult to help you without seeing the JavaScript. You could probably fix your problem by just using some CSS to restrict the size of the images but without seeing the JavaScript we won't know *why* they're stretched out to begin with

Comment: dont reinvent the wheel when all this has been figured out for you https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/